# Accessing group variables in VSTS Online

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using group variables in a VSTS Online project, and I need to access a variable of a group called GlobalGroupA from a powershell script in the release pipeline. Does anyone know how to do this?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

It was the same as accessing a local variable.
$(variable)